# Featured content slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I am looking for a content slider that I can use to feature 3-5 press releases at a time.

I like pretty much everything about this one: http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/featured-content-slider/, but I'm having some issues customizing it to fit my needs. My problem is that not all of the press releases will have accompanying photos; some of them will be just text. This slider seems more suited to items with images + text.

Does anyone know of a slider that accommodates both items with text AND items with photos + text? Or can anyone help me tweak this slider so that it fits what I need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I hope this will help you

```
#fragment-1 img
{
display:none;
}

#fragment-1 .info
 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  height: 250px;!important
}
```

**working** [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/STubQ/)

I hide the picture of the first tab and I set .info on top with height of 250px

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what you're looking for, but you could use a service such as [this one](http://zenithwebtechnologies.com.au/auto-thumbnail-generation-from-url.html) to take screenshots of the press releases automatically, and use those as the corresponding image.